# Get the "Smart" group of a user id via REST

Tags: api, groups, smartgroups, rest

We've created so called 'smart' groups in civicrm, and we need to know if a certrain user belongs to this group.

I can get the groups of a user with the following code:

http://url.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?debug=0&entity=GroupContact&action=get&contact_id='.$uid.'&json={"sequential":1}&api_key='.$api_key.'&key='.$site_key

But the "Smart group of the UID is not listed here,. When I do the following:

http://url.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?debug=0&entity=Contact&action=get**&group='.$gid.'**&version=3&contact_id='.$uid.'&json={"sequential":1}&api_key='.$api_key.'&key='.$site_key

I get the result, that the user belongs to this group.

What I want is only to give the contact_id as parameter to check in which smart groups this user is

Answer (score 1):

Smart Groups are basically a saved search. Checking whether a given contact is in a saved search result means running the search for that combination, which is not efficient - hence the reason the information you want isn't available through existing APIs.

See eg [CRM-11903: GroupContact API doesn't get smart group members](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11903).

If you want to be able to query the API for this information, you have some options -

- As you're doing, use the Contact API and filter by group ID to check each Contact/Smart group pair. Not efficient, but you've already found it works.
- Create a "regular" group and automate the process of updating its members based on the criteria of your smart group. A bit rough - but probably not too hard.
- Implement the functionality you need in a new API method. Probably not as hard as it sounds, check [existing API methods for examples](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/api/v3).

Comment: While it can't be relied on, it might help you to know there's also a DB table which caches the mapping of contacts to groups incl smart groups: `civicrm_group_contact_cache` - just remember it's a *cache* table so not to be trusted!